# To display a date list using html, js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I would like to recreate this date list using html and js: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nQzp.png). When user clicked the right arrow button, the date list will start on the following week, which is 29 Oct, Sat. Same goes also when user clicked the left arrow button.

This is my testing.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="datelist.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="curr_week_days('22-10-2021')">

    <div style="border-radius: 5px; margin: 25px 0;">                    
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="lnkDatesPrev" onclick="prev_week_days()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right arrow liLastDaysTabNew">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="lnkDatesNext" onclick="next_week_days()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class="uldaysTabNew">
                <div id="display_list" onload="display_li()"></div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

From testing.html, I entered the date value using onload="curr_week_days('22-10-2021')".

And this is my datelist.js:

```
var daysRequired = 7;

function curr_week_days(dateInsert)
{
   const days = [];
   days.push(dateInsert);

   for (var i = 1; i <= daysRequired; i++)
   {
      days.push(moment().add(i, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY')); 

      dayLast = days[i]; 
   }

   return dayLast;
   //need also to pass the days array into function display_li()
}

function display_li() 
{
   const dayNext = [];

   //stuck at here
   dayNext.push(curr_week_days()); 

   document.getElementById('display_list').innerHTML = dayNext;
}

function next_week_days()
{
   const day_next =[];
   day_next.push(curr_week_days(dayLast));

   for (var i = 1; i <= daysRequired; i++)
   {
       day_next.push(moment().add(i, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
   }

   return day_next;
}

function prev_week_days()
{
   var day_next = [];

   for (var i = daysRequired; i >= 1; i--)
   {
       days.push(moment().subtract(i, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY')); 
   }

   return day_next;
}
```

For some reason also, the value inside the days array shows the current date and does not continue from 22-10-2021. I know my code is pretty messy and there is an easy way to do it. Kindly need your guys help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you made day_next a global variable so that every click (prev / next) will save your data and you only need to do is display it

Comment: Following the DRY principle you can combine those 3 functions : curr_week_days, next_week_days, prev_week_days as they do the same and make it with fuction printWeek for example that will accept just the first/starting day. This way on click of prev and next you’ll need just to figure out the starting day which can be stored as global var for example. Initially/ onload you’ll set it to the day you want to start with and then call printWeek with it.

Comment: @ЕмилЦоков I dont really get it. Can you provide with a simple example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example of what I ment in my comment

```js
  let weekDays = [];
  const daysRequired = 7;
  function printWeek(start){
    let weekHTML = ''
    weekDays = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= daysRequired; i++) {
      weekDays.push(
      dateFns.addDays(start, i-1)
      ); 
      weekHTML += `<li>
      ${dateFns.format(dateFns.addDays(start, i-1), 'DD-MM-YYYY')}          </li>`;
    }
    document.getElementById('display_list').innerHTML = weekHTML;
    
  }
  printWeek(new Date());
  
function prev_week_days() {
  printWeek(dateFns.subDays(weekDays[0], daysRequired))
}

function next_week_days() {
  printWeek(dateFns.addDays(weekDays[6], daysRequired))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.28.5/date_fns.min.js"></script>
<div style="border-radius: 5px; margin: 25px 0;">                    
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="lnkDatesPrev" onclick="prev_week_days()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left">prev</i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right arrow liLastDaysTabNew">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="lnkDatesNext" onclick="next_week_days()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right">next</i></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class="uldaysTabNew" id="display_list" >
                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

NB! About this code in your example html:

```
<ul class="uldaysTabNew">
            <div id="display_list" onload="display_li()"></div>
</ul>
```

is invalid HTML ad you can only have li tags inside ul tag